# redraw path on a sufaceview when screen orientation changes

Tags: android, screen, orientation, surfaceview

my app is working fine but when screen orientation changes the surfaceview is cleared. i am using path to draw free hand.i am trying to use  arraylist of path to restore it to the original state.

below is the constructor of the class in which i initialize arraylist

```
public DrawThread(Context context){

            this.context = context;
            paths = new ArrayList<Path>();  //this is the arraylist in which i store path.
            //path = new Path();
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        }
```

below are the functions responsible for drawing path

```
boolean doTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {   

            int eventaction = event.getAction();
            int X = (int)event.getX();
            int Y = (int)event.getY();
            switch (eventaction ) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                path = new Path();



                path.moveTo(X, Y);
                path.lineTo(X, Y);

                 break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //path.close();
                //path.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
                path.lineTo(X, Y);


             break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                path.lineTo(X, Y);

                //path.setLastPoint(X, Y);
                paths.add(path);


            break;
            }
            drawOnCanvas();

            return true;
    }


private void drawOnCanvas(){

            Canvas canvas = null;
            try{
                canvas = sHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                    if(canvas != null & path!= null){

                            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

                }
            }finally {
                if(canvas!=null){
                    sHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }

        }
```

below is the function responsible for restoring surfaceview to original state.

setSurfaceSize is called when screen orientation changes.

```
public void setSurfaceSize(int width , int height){

            sWidth = width;
            sHeight = height;
            redrawall();

        }
private void redrawall(){
            Canvas canvas = null;
            int i = 0;
            try{
                canvas = sHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                    if(canvas != null & paths!= null){
                        if(paths.isEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(context, "empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        for (Path pp : paths){    
                            canvas.drawPath(pp, paint);
                        }

                        }

            }finally {
                if(canvas!=null){
                    sHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
```

problem is paths(the arraylist) is always empty and the screen remains blank after rotation.

Comment: The orientation change will pause and resume the activity.  Are you storing your state in static variables?

Comment: Thanks for replying fadden. I am using path to draw on screen. I am storing path in an arraylist. Which I use to restore screen to the original state ,but that arraylist is always empty. I am having trouble uderstanding why arraylist is empty.

Answer (score 1):

For each rotation of the device, the `Activity` is destroyed and re-created. It calls `onPause()`, `onStop()`, and recalls `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`, so as your custom view. Therefore, the `DrawThread` is stopped and destroyed and recalls its initialization method (its constructors). Then, each time, it creates a new `ArrayList` with this line:

```
// this list is obviously empty at its creation ;)
paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
```

To prevent this, store your list's state using `Parcelable` objects before the rotation and restore it after. You will probably need to create a custom `Path` object to implement the `Parcelable` object to it and then, save the `ArrayList`. With a little research on internet, you can find these methods to add in your view:

```
// Saves current instance of class
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() { ... }

// Restores current instance of class
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) { ... }

// State of class
private static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
    ...
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) { ... }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
            new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
        public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) { ... }
        public SavedState[] newArray(int size) { ... }
    };
}
```